# Can I arrange for TSA to pre-approve an item for carry-on luggage?

Tags: usa, air-travel, airport-security, hand-luggage, tsa

The TSA website [gives](https://www.dhs.gov/learn-what-i-can-bring-plane) a list of permitted items for the carry-on. However, they also mention that the final decision lies in the hand of the security agents. Is it possible to ask the TSA to "pre-approve" my item for carry-on luggage, before I check in for my flight (e.g., a few days before my flight)?

By "pre-approve" my item, I mean having my item pre-inspected prior to a flight and then brought onto the plane without further inspection (or at least not getting refused because the security changed their mind).

Comment: Is this something that would definitely be approved if it went in checked baggage?

Comment: @DJClayworth yes, nothing exotic

Comment: Can you imagine the outcry if a "pre-approved" item turns out to be a weapon that is then used in an attack, or a dangerous item that causes a crash?  And the screener from the day of the flight goes on TV: "I thought the item looked suspicious, and I didn't want to let it on the flight, but the TSA bureaucrats had pre-approved it so my concerns were ignored."  Even if you think "it's all security theater", think of what *bad* theater that would be.

Comment: @NateEldredge it's easy to find some ways to mitigate the issue, eg a compromise could be not to throw away pre-approved items that turn out to be refused on the day of the flight. Also the pre-approval would be done by the same screeners, and not some random bureaucrats. I could easily give more ideas but anyway it seems the answer to my question is negative. I didn't mean to write a new policy, just be aware of what the current policies are to make sure I hadn't missed anything the day they throw away my laptop, microphone or massager thinking that this is a blunt item.

Comment: The TSA doesn't throw away prohibited carry-on items unless you relinquish them; you have the option of taking your stuff and leaving (e.g. to check the bag, put something in your car, find a place to mail your item, cancel your plane tickets and travel by another mode, give up on your trip, build a rocket ship and blast off to the moon, etc...) if you want to, though that may interfere with your travel plans.

Comment: @ZachLipton sure. You know what I meant. A better option than giving up one's trip.

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if "pre-approve" is the correct term for this question.  If you mean have the item pre-inspected prior to a flight and then brought onto the plane without further inspection, then @Hilmar's response is correct.  However if you mean prior to the flight to ask the TSA in general if an item is allowed as hand luggage, and still go through an inspection on the day of flight, then there is nothing stopping you calling the TSA to ask.  Again, the answer by Hilmar's answer is correct in that the final decision is solely at the discretion of TSA staff on the day of travel.

Comment: @PeterM Thanks, I meant the former, i.e. "have the item pre-inspected prior to a flight and then brought onto the plane without further inspection".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unlikely.

The final decision whether an item is allowed rests with the staff on the ground and any pre-approval would overrule this policy. A pre-approval would also require the item to be inspected and than "sealed" so it cannot be modified or tampered with between the pre-approval and the actual flight.

I travel with two items that often get flagged: a measurement microphone and (strangely) a Rubik's Cube. I have repeatedly asked TSA officers on how best to handle this, but have got no coherent replies. TSA behavior is inconsistent: you take them out: you get yelled at. You don't take them out: you get yelled at. Same of telling them up front: sometimes the appreciated it and sometimes they get annoyed and you get yelled at.

Comment: The yelling or not yelling was my experience pre-TSA.  So nothing has really changed.

Comment: Thanks. My bag with simply laptop, charger, massager, keyboard and microphone often gets flagged but I've never been yelled at so far.

Comment: "yelled at" here means "given a stern talking to about what I did wrong". Heck, I once got yelled at for carrying a stick deodorant which according to the TSA (and any other agent) is perfectly fine. However this security officer decided otherwise. I got a stern talking to about how this must be go in the zip lock bag (which it doesn't) and that it was too big (which it wasn't). I offered to just throw it away (to get on with life), but she insisted on more lecturing and then still let me keep it.

Comment: There is even disagreement between different agents in the same line. I have been chided for taking out / not taking out something, following instructions by another agent twenty seconds earlier. They each make it up as they feel.